# NumPy: tile up to specific size

Tags: numpy, tile

Let us say we have a pattern

```py
x = np.array([1,2,3])
```

And we would like to repeat the pattern to fill an array of size `n >> x.size`.

We could do something like:

```py
np.tile(x, 1 + (n // x.size))[:n]
```

We could do something similar for 2-d arrays base on shape. (rather than size) and abstract it as a function.

As an example with a 2-d array:

```py
pattern = np.array([[1,2],[4,5]])
n_rows = 7
n_cols = 5
np.tile(
    pattern,
    (1 + (n_rows // pattern.shape[0]), 1 + (n_cols // pattern.shape[1]))
)[:n_rows, :n_cols] 

Out:
array([[1, 2, 1, 2, 1],
       [4, 5, 4, 5, 4],
       [1, 2, 1, 2, 1],
       [4, 5, 4, 5, 4],
       [1, 2, 1, 2, 1],
       [4, 5, 4, 5, 4],
       [1, 2, 1, 2, 1]])
```

My question: is there a native way of doing that in NumPy?

Comment: can you provide an example with a small 2d array with expected output, plz?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not aware of a function like this natively, but your solution seems quite nice to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it slightly more general, but there is no built in function for this

```py
x = np.array([[1, 2],
              [4, 5]])
shape = (7, 5)

np.tile(x, np.array(shape)//np.array(np.shape(x)) + 1)[tuple(map(slice, shape))]
```